# PHP Break successive If Statements

Tags: php

I have a large set of if statements that when one of them is true then the following if statements don't need to be tested.

I don't know what the best way to do this is.

Should I create a function, switch or while loop?

Each successive if statement is different and has the input values created beforehand. I shall try and create a simple example to try and explain this better.

```
$total = ($val1+$val2+$val3)/$arbitaryvalue
if($total > 2){//Do Something
}

$total = ($val1+$val2)/$anothervalue
if($total > 2){//Do Something different
}
```

Comment: Utilizing `if` statements would be a complete nightmare in your situation.  I would advocate using either a function or storing your conditions in an object or array and iterating accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pop them inside the else of the previous if statement, that'll mean the only run if the first condition evaluates to false. This will get messy if you've got a lot of if statements though, is the example in your question representative of the scale of your requirements?

```
$total = ($val1+$val2+$val3)/$arbitaryvalue
if($total > 2){//Do Something
}
else
{

    $total = ($val1+$val2)/$anothervalue
        if($total > 2){//Do Something different
    }

}
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of this! Such a simple answer. Although I have around 18 successive if statements so this would get messy fast

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( condition ) {

}

else if ( another_condition ) {

} 

... 

else if ( another_condition ) {

}
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

Deciding whether to go with a loop would depend on a real example. If there is a pattern to how $total is set, then we could go with a loop. If not, it might be better just to do successive if statements:

```
if(($val1+$val2+$val3)/$arbitraryvalue > 2){
   //Do Something
}
else if(($val1+$val2)/$anothervalue > 2)
{
   //Do something different
}
```

However, if there is a pattern to the $val1+$val2 and $anothervalue parts, a loop might be the better solution. In my opinion, your decision should also be contingent upon whether the pattern makes sense or not.

Answer (score 0):

Since using `else` would not be beneficial and difficult to maintain, I would suggest utilizing a function.

A function would be more ideal as you can exit the function at any time once a condition has been met by using `return`.

> If called from within a function, the return statement immediately
>   ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as
>   the value of the function call.

Included below is a sample function with dummy values set for demonstration purposes:

```
<?php

function checkConditions(){   
    $val1 = 5;
    $val2 = 10;
    $val3 = 8;

    $arbitaryvalue = 5;
    $anothervalue = 4;

    $total = ($val1+$val2+$val3) / $arbitaryvalue;

    if($total > 2){
        return 'condition 1';
    }  

    $total = ($val1+$val2) / $anothervalue;
    if($total > 2){
        return 'condition 2';
    } 

    return 'no conditions met';
}

echo checkConditions();
?>
```

If you want to perform some type of action as indicated in your commented code, then you can perform the appropriate action before returning from the function.

Answer (score 0):

What Ben Everard says is the correct way, but there are many other solutions:

```
$conditions = array(
  array(
    'condition' => ($val1+$val2+$val3)/$arbitaryvalue,
    'todo' => 'doSomething',
  ),
  array(
    'condition' => ($val1+$val2)/$arbitaryvalue,
    'todo' => 'doSomethingDifferent',
  ),
  // ...
);

foreach ($conditions as $item)
{
  if ($item['condition'])
  {
    // $item['todo']();
    call_user_func($item['todo']);
    break;
  }
}


function doSomething()
{
  // ...
}

function doSomethingDifferent()
{
  // ...
}
```